# Upload.php file only working for png file type

Tags: php

my upload.php is only uploading a png image type.In my code i've allowed extensions of (jpg,png,jpeg,gif) to be uploaded.I expect that i am able to upload the image stated without issues.

In my code i think there is an issue with $_FILES variable.I've tried to print to the screen the $_FILES variable and it displays the image file information of a png image,but fails to print to the screen the image information of an image with different extension.

```
    <?php

if(isset($_POST['submitpics'])){

  $file=$_FILES['upfile'];
 printr($file); exit();

  $filename=$_FILES['upfile']['name'];
  $filetype=$_FILES['upfile']['type'];
  $fileerror=$_FILES['upfile']['error'];
  $filesize=$_FILES['upfile']['size'];
  $filetmp_name=$_FILES['upfile']['tmp_name'];

  $fileext=explode(".", $filename);
  $fileactualext=strtolower(end($fileext));

   $allowed=array( jpg, jpeg, gif, png); //allowed extensions

   if(in_array($fileactualext,$allowed)){
         if($fileerror == 0){
           if($filesize < 4000000){
              $filenamenew="profile".$id.".".$fileactualext;
              $filedestination="uploads/".$filenamenew;

              move_uploaded_file($filetmp_name, $filedestination);
              $sql="UPDATE profileimg SET status = 0 WHERE userid='$id';";
              mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
              header("Location: index.php");
               } else{
                    echo "<strong>File too large</strong>";
                    exit();
                    }            

            } else {
                echo "<strong>An error occured</strong>";
                   }
       } else {
           echo "<h2>This file is not allowed!</h2>";
              }
}
```

according to the code above,i only printed $_FILES variable to the screen to find out if the image information was actually collected by the super global variable($_FILES).And when i uploaded png image ,it worked but when i uploaded jpg image or any other extension,it fails.

And when i upload an image that isn't png without this line of code(`printr($file); exit();` ) ,i get an error message from google saying "The site can't be reached".

generally all i need is to be able to upload the images i've specified.
And i don't know where error is in my code.I need some help please!!

Comment: _Show us_ what $_FILES contains in that situation.

Answer (score 0):

welcome to stackoverflow.

I can see two problems in your post. The first one is that this line

`$allowed=array( jpg, jpeg, gif, png); //allowed extensions`

should be

`$allowed=array( "jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png"); //allowed extensions`

because you want to match strings (text). The other thing is the error you are getting: `i get an error message from google saying "The site can't be reached"`

Seems that, for some reason, you are redirecting to a domain that is not available, probably not your site. It's strange that this happens only when you upload a file that is not a png, but maybe you have some javascript code doing something else in your frontend.

You can update your question with the webpage you use to post to your backend code if you need further help.

Let me recommend a debug tool to make development easy: https://xdebug.org/ you can put breakpoints in your code and run it line per line to understand better what's going on. You can use xdebug with almost any known IDE to make it simple to debug.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

instead of explode , use pathinfo to get correct extension

```
$filename=$_FILES['upfile']['name'];
$fileext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

more details about pathinfo [`pathinfo()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
$info = new SplFileInfo($_FILES['upfile']['name']);
$extension=$info->getExtension();


if($extension=='png')
{


   DoUpload();

}
```

Also u can get size of file with Splfileinfo class or more data

```
$size=$info->getSize();
```

For get type of file

```
$fileType=$info->getType();
```

Comment: I guess i have issues with my processor and graphics card. The same code works on a different computer but not on mine.                        A low definition png is uploaded successfully but not a HD one.   But still it won't allow for any jpg image